# How to translate a Django application using Poedit?

Tags: django, localization, poedit

I run `django-admin makemessages -l ro -e html,txt,rml` in the application's directory (above the `locale` directory) to generate the PO files. When I open a PO file with Poedit, e.g. `locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`, I can not see where the message is being referenced. The paths from the catalog look like this:

```
#: admin.py:12 admin.py:23
```

so Poedit tries to open `locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/admin.py` which of course does not exist.

Update:

```
find -path '*/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/django.po' -exec sed --in-place -r '/^#: / s/([a-zA-Z_./]+):([0-9]+)/..\/..\/..\/\1:\2/g' {} \+
```

fixes the paths, but I would still like to see this problem solved at its core.

I've also reported this on [Django's bug tracker](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13936).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [**poedit-users**](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.poedit.user/973) mailing list thread (yes, that was the best place to ask).

Update: ​Poedit handles this case correctly since version 1.5.6.

Comment: What about using `X-Poedit-Basepath: ../../../\n`? It seems to work for me.